# Genetic Algorithm for Flow shop Scheduling

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I need help in Matlab: I need to find out how to Crossover any two sequences for genetic alghorithm in FlowShop, e.g.

> 1st sequence = 1 5 4 7 3 2 9 8 10 6
>
> 2nd sequence = 7 8 9 10 5 4 2 1 3 6

after crossover, the off-springs should be

> offspring 1 = 1 5 4 7 3 2  8 9 10 6
>
> offspring 2 = 7 8 9 10 1 5 4  3 2 6

Crossover should be such that each number doesn't repeat itself in the offspring sequence. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: The example you provided is not very clear. Number `7` is repeated both in the 1st and 2nd offspring.

Comment: @Alessiox I believe that she means that it's a different permutation of the inputs in which none of the values of one are at the same *location* as they are in the offspring.

Comment: Alessiox,   that was a mistakenly typed,, thank you for the mention, i remove the repeated number in each offspring,,

Comment: how is it possible  in Matlab ?

Comment: Suever is so right.. how is it possible  in Matlab as i had completed some portion of my thesis in matlab,now i can't switch to C++ .

Comment: @sarah surely you can write in Matlab your own crossover function (have a look at here http://it.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html?refresh=true#f7820) however this looks to me like a very strange way to create children since a child has only one parent in your case: 1st offspring is permutation of 1st parent and 2nd offspring in permutation of 2nd parent.

Comment: @sarah If I understood correctly (1 parent generates 1 child) you can perform the following in order to swap random indices without repetitions. First of all, initialize the child as a complete copy of the parent (`p1=[1 5 4 7 3 2 9 8 10 6]` and then `c1=p1`). Then you can select two random indices from the parent `idx=randi(length(p1),1,2)`. Now `idx` will be a vector of 2 random elements and we want to swap the two indices. The swap can be done thanks to `c1(fliplr(idx))=p1(idx)`.

Comment: ALessiox,  what you explain is my another step in Matlab , that is called "mutation",  Thanks alot for solving my next step in advance. hehe.

Comment: i am doing Genetic Alghorithm for General Flow SHop scheduling , in which i conside 10 jobs to be process on 3 machines,, in genetic alghorithm first step is making population of permutaiton, then taking sample if few sequence,, then taking two parents sequence from sample, then making off springs through crossover and then mutation,, so what you did was Mutation " to flip two number in a single sequence". Thanks Man. Alessiox

Comment: for each sequence, e.g, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10,,    all jobs will follow this sequence through all 3 machines, now i am looking for Gantt Chart in matlab using "Plot".. to calculate processing time, (Cmax)..  can you do it ? hehe,, you will solve my months of work in matter of mints i guess :D

Comment: @sarah, do not confuse mutation with crossover. What I've explained so far is the crossover operator as you described it. During the mutation stage it is true that several chromosomes will be changed, although you do not necessarily change them by flipping them with other chromosomes. You can as well randomly change chromosomes and the mutation operator does not ensure (unless you write the code for it) that the elements are unique. If you want unique elements than sure, flipping chromosomes is a good way to go, although you must re-declare the crossover operator.

Comment: @sarah, Your crossover operator (if I understood correctly!) indeed looks much more like a mutation because as far as I can see from your examples you create child 1 starting from parent 1 and child 2 starting from parent 2. Apparently there is no "mixture" between parents.

Comment: @sarah, to make your crossover more robust, I'd suggest to implement some sort of scattered crossover (grab random samples from parent 1 and random samples from parent 2) with the constraint that in the child the elements must be unique. Later on, you can as well implement mutation by flipping a given number of chromosome pairs.

Comment: thank you, you explain very well. Alessiox

Comment: Alessiox,  can you help me how to perform scattered crossover exactly as you said it,   in matlab ?

Comment: @sarah, have a look at the link I've posted above. It explains everything. However, I should warn you that if your genetic code has only integers (e.g. in range 1 to 10 as above), Matlab has some default behavior and you should carefully read the guide above in order to understand what you must/can do in case of Integer problems

Comment: ok thanks Alessiox

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of existing crossovers defined for permutation encodings. Among them the following would be useful for you:

- Cyclic Crossover
- Partially Matched Crossover
- Uniform-like Crossover
- Position-based Crossover

These crossovers aim to preserve the position of the job in the permutation. You can find implementations in C# in the PermutationEncoding plugin of [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac.fcgi/browser/trunk/sources/HeuristicLab.Encodings.PermutationEncoding/3.3/Crossovers). Browse the source files and you can also find references to scientific articles that describe these crossovers.