# how to Crossover without Repeatition

Tags: scheduling, genetic-algorithm

i am doing Static Flow-Shop Scheduling problem, i considered 10 tasks and 3 machines. in permutation i face many possible sequence through which tasks should go through machines.
now i consider the following two sequence and i would like how to crossover them in order to get  non-repetitive child chromosomes .

first sequence = T3 T2 T5 T6 T9 T1 T4 T7 T8 T10

second sequence= T3 T2 T6 T8 T1 T5 T4 T7 T9 T10

now how to make child-sequence so that it does not have repetition and all task are present in child-sequence as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Genetic Algorithm for Flow shop Scheduling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667052/genetic-algorithm-for-flow-shop-scheduling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does **not** include any code for us to review, thus I conclude that you need a general idea for doing it.

---

**Possible Solution:**

This would be the *canonic* approach for a **position-based** crossover. Genes in the same position in both parents are *not moved* around, whereas genes occupying different positions are exchanged with one another with a *two-step* transition:

1. **clone:** create child **c1** copy of **p1** and **c2** copy of **p2**
2. **slice:** compute the set of indexes for which **c1** and **c2** have a different value in the same position
3. **randomize:** pick a random **idx** from this set, and remove it from the set
4. **swap:** pick a random index **idx** in this set: if **v1** is in position **idx** in **c1** and **v2** is in position **idx** in **c2**, **swap** the values so that **v1** is now at position **idx** in **c2** and **v2** is in position **idx** in **c1**
5. **compensate:** find the index **idy** s.t. **v2** is at position **idy** in **p1** and index **idz** s.t. **v1** is at position **idz** in **p2** and compensate the swap operation so that now **v1** is at position **idy** in **c1** and **v2** is at position **idz** in **c2**. Remove both **idy** and **idz** from the index set of points 2/3.
6. **reiterate:** with probability **p**, go back to step 3.

**Example:**

```
// idx = 8, indexes start from 0
|3 2| 9 6 5 8 |4 7| 1 |10| // c1
         /          |
|3 2| 6 1 8 9 |4 7| 5 |10| // c2
=
|3 2| 9 6 1 8 |4 7| 5 |10| // c1
|3 2| 6 5 8 9 |4 7| 1 |10| // c2
```

**Considerations:**

As you can see, the **crossover** degenerates into a **guided mutation**, and this is due to the *constraint* of not introducing repetitions within your genetic code. However, it is still different from **mutation**, as the latter would also affect genes that are in the same position for both parents.